# Apply a "webkit-keyframes" ONLY inside the id

Tags: html, css

how can i apply the "webkit-keyframes" only inside the id #progress1? I want to do this because there will be another progress bar (#progress2) in the page with a different webkit-keyframes.

```
#progress1 {
    background: white; /*-- Color of the bar --*/
    height: 30px;
    width: 0%;
    max-width: 100%;
    float: left;
    -webkit-animation: progress 2s 1 forwards;
    -moz-animation: progress 2s 1 forwards;
    -ms-animation: progress 2s 1 forwards;
    animation: progress 2s 1 forwards;
}



@-webkit-keyframes progress { 
    from { }

    to { width: 36% }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't possible to scope animations in CSS. Just give them different names. Don't call them both `progress`.

Comment: But for some reason when I change the name progress to progress1 the animation does not work.

Comment: that's weird... it does work now! Don't know why it didn't work before. Thanks!